# Login with google playgames

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-play-games

What I'm trying to do:
-Automatically login into google playgames account when my flutter application starts

The error I get:
`PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`

Thats what I tried

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@strings/game_services_project_id"/>
```

- Added the below in res/strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
        <string translatable="false"  name="game_services_project_id"> >>PROJECT_ID<< </string>
        </resources>
```

- the flutter code to sign in using play games:

```
signIn() async {
            try {
              
              final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(
                signInOption: SignInOption.games,
              ).signIn();
              final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication.then((value) {
                print("googleAuthen========");
              });
              if (googleAuth != null) {
                // Create a new credential
                print("googleAuth=======");
                final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
                  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
                );
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
              }
            } catch (error) {
              print('Error during Google sign-in: $error');
            }
         }
```

I expected to signin with playgames but I got this error
`PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`

Comment: is your id add as tester in play console?

Comment: Yes I added it as a tester